# Why Eigen does not resolve built-in symbols? (all, last, seq, etc...)

Tags: c++, eigen3

I have this piece of code form the Eigen [documentation](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/group__TutorialSlicingIndexing.html) site about slicing and indexing:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Eigen/Dense>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
using namespace Eigen;

int main() {
    std::vector<int> ind{4,2,5,5,3};
    MatrixXi A = MatrixXi::Random(4,6);
    cout << "Initial matrix A:\n" << A << "\n\n";
    cout << "A(all,ind):\n" << A(all,ind) << "\n\n";

    return 0;
}
```

When I try to compile, I get multiple errors, for example:

- `all` is not a member of `Eigen`
- `all` was not declared in this scope
- `last` was not declared in this scope
- `seq` is not a member of `Eigen`
- Function `seq` could not be resolved
- `MatrixXi::Random` invalid arguments

**How can I fix these errors?**

---

It looks as if I had the wrong version of Eigen (it worked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16553906/block-operations-wont-work-on-eigen)), however, according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21497064/how-to-check-the-version-number-of-eigen-c-template-library) answer I have:
`EIGEN_WORLD_VERSION 3`
`EIGEN_MAJOR_VERSION 3`
`EIGEN_MINOR_VERSION 7`,
which I believe is the latest.

As far as installation is concerned, I copied the `Eigen` folder to the project location and supplied a path (-I flag) to *one folder above it* for a g++ compiler. The library itself seems to work well; for example, this code (from supplied examples) works fine:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Eigen/Dense>

using namespace Eigen;
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  Matrix3d m = Matrix3d::Random();
  m = (m + Matrix3d::Constant(1.2)) * 50;
  cout << "m =" << endl << m << endl;
  Vector3d v(1,2,3);
  
  cout << "m * v =" << endl << m * v << endl;
}
```

Comment: Using 2 huge namespaces will lead to namespace collisions. I urge you to avoid that and hope it's just for the example.

Comment: This is a snippet directly from the example `QuickStart_example2_fixed.cpp`, but thanks for the good advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is probably the `-I` option to g++

I suspect you have something like:

```
g++  ....  -I<path_to_project>/Eigen
```

... whereas it should only be

```
g++  ....  -I<path_to_project>
```

... i.e., the final `Eigen` directory should not be on the include path.

Make this change, and then also change the source code so that all includes are like:

```
#include <Eigen/Dense>
#include <Eigen/Cholesky>
```

Additionally, you are referring to a variable `all` but your program has not defined it.

Also ensure you are enabling c++11 compiler option at least.

---

**EDIT:**

For completeness sake, I add the answer that appeared in the comments.
The documentation in OP's question refers to the 3.3.9 version which does not support symbols `all`, `last`,`seq`. For the most recent stable (3.3.7) version [`block`](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialBlockOperations.html) or [`reshape`](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialReshapeSlicing.html) operators must be used.

The lesson here is: *always check if the documentation version matches the version of the used library*.

Comment: I changed the code accordingly to your advice. The `#include <Eigen/Dense>` part works at this point, but I still get those errors. Correct me if I'm wrong, but isn't the symbol `all` a part of `Eigen` namespace and should be defined in an appropriate `#include` directive? Thus I wouldn't need to defile it in my `main()`.

Comment: Well, according the document link you provided (which is development branch 3.3.9) the `all` should exist,  but you've noted your local version is 3.3.7  ... which is the latest stable version.

Comment: ... indeed if I compile your program against 3.3.90  it does succeed (although I use  explicit namespace also, eg, `Eigen::all`)